Boot fails on Nvidia hybrid graphics
I have a Geforce GTX 960M + Intel HD Graphics 530 combo, and Ubuntu (24.04) only boots in "recovery mode".
I have prime-select set to Intel but that doesn't resolve the problem either.
I have written about other details of this elsewhere:
Ubuntu 24.04 won't boot on Nvidia 500-series drivers

Can someone explain the downvote?

I've had a similar problem on a new build - there is no output on the nvidia card or the onboard video chip. I ended up plugging and re-plugging the video card and that somehow fixed it. I'm not sure how - nothing changed in the BIOS, I wasn't able to make any changes in the BIOS as nothing would show on the monitor.

@ventsyv , Since the issue got temporarily resolved by switching to the more legacy 470-nvidia-driver, and got unresolved again by a subsequent driver update, I think this is a driver-issue, and not a hardware one.
